# iOS Draw a line above label

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I have a label in my view. Now I want to draw a line above the label, which means you can see the label is under the line.

So far I can draw a line using quartz2D but always under the label. Is there any way to solve my problems?

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: You could make a UIView that's two points high.

Comment: When you say "under the label", do you mean that the label is obscuring the line (in which case, if you change the label's background color to clear)? Or are you saying that the `y` coordinate of the line you drew was such that it appeared at the bottom of the label instead of the top of it?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `CAShapeLayer` like this:

```
CAShapeLayer *lineLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
lineLayer.frame = self.label.bounds;
lineLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMidY(lineLayer.bounds), lineLayer.bounds.size.width, 2);
lineLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect].CGPath;
```

And then add it to the `UILabel` like this:

```
[self.label.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the easiest thing to do is to create a 2x2 pixel image called line@2x.png, and have the bottom 2 pixels black, the top 2 transparent, then use it as the background image for an image view. Stretch the image view to whatever width you need by using it as a pattern image. The 1x image should be a 1x1px, all black.

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; // Whatever frame the line needs

// Add the line image as a pattern
UIColor *patternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"]];
lineView.backgroundColor = patternColor;
[self.view addSubview:lineView];
```

Comment: Why use an image? Just set the `backgroundColor` of `lineView` to whatever line color you need and make `lineView` just one or two points tall.

Comment: Yeah, That is kind of a solution.

Comment: @rmaddy With an image you can make a thin 1 pixel line on Retina display and don't have to deal with extra conditionals with screen scale.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a label you will be using a lot, you could make a sub-class of UILabel and override the drawRect function.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    [super drawRect:r];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width - 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

The advantage here is that the line will be "baked" into the view and only be draw once. Other methods such as CAShapeLayer or UIView will be re-rendered every frame.

For bonus points, you can make the color and line width properties :)